# Minsweeper game advice

Tags: java

I am currently in the process of making a java minesweeper game for school and have run into a problem.  I have created an array of 64 buttons arranged in a grid layout.  The problem i am having is getting the x and y co-ordinates of a particular button pressed and sending these co-ordinates to another class which contains a 2d array.  any suggestions on how i can obtain the x and y position of the button pressed???
any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know the click position you can use basic math to get the square hit. Then it's object-oriented programming to give that info to other parts of the game. You could follow a MVC (Model View Controller) pattern.

Basically your controller (main part) will register as listening to your view (your button(s)).

[Here is a similar game with source code included](http://www.beroux.com/english/softwares/mountnfall/) if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the x-y coordinates on the canvas or just the x and y as in which column/row the button is?

If it's the latter just ensure that the other class can listen to events, and fire an event with the coordinates.

```
class OtherClass {
     public void fireEvent(MineSweepButton button);
}
```

and for your button:

```
class MineSweepButton extends JButton {
     private int x;
     private int y;

     public MineSweepButton(String text, int x, int y) {
           super(text);
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;               
     }
}
```

Now add an action listener that fires an event on the OtherClass.